# Implementing WSO2 SSO

Tags: java, wso2

I am trying to implement WSO2 SSO in my app. I tried the example app successfully. 
I have created a small example with spring mvc. My problem is now, that the request goes to WSO2 server and is redirected back, but without success. I am checking the result in the returning url, but the `SSOAgentSessionBean` is always null.

```
SSOAgentSessionBean bean = (SSOAgentSessionBean)request.getSession().getAttribute(SSOAgentConfigs.getSessionBeanName());
```

I added the filter (which also forces the redirect). That works:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SSOFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SSOFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginarea/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So my question is:
how do I see why the result of the back-redirect is failing? Are there any logs I can enable?

regards
Leon

Comment: which version of SSOAgentSessionBean that y are using ?

Comment: I don't remember it was 2 years ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

goto log4j.properties on /repository/conf folder change

log4j.logger.org.wso2=INFO to DEBUG

You can get more details on below article

http://soasecurity.org/2014/02/26/how-to-wso2is-troubleshooting-wso2-identity-server-1/